# Room delete query does not remove the row in database

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm using `@Query` to delete row in my Room database, but I'm not able to delete the record. Here is my query from `@Dao`

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(final Note note);

    @Update
    void update(final Note note);

    @Query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE uid = :noteId")
    int delete(final int noteId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes")
    LiveData<List<Note>> selectAll();
}
```

Entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class Note {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    private int mId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "uid")
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int mUid;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "text")
    @SerializedName("text")
    private String mText;

    public Note() {
    }

    getters and setters ommited

}
```

Can someone give me an advice, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you determining that you are not successfully deleting the row?

Comment: My delete method is int and if I understood correctly from documentation -  UPDATE or DELETE queries can return void or int. If it is an int, the value is the number of rows affected by this query. - My delete method returns always 0. On the other hand if I select records, "deleted" record is there.

Comment: Perhaps there is something out of sync with your entity. I recommend that you edit your question and post the source code to the `@Entity` that is defining the `notes` table.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited my question with Entity and Dao class

Comment: Assuming that you're not mixing up the `id` and `uid` values, what you have seems fine. If you can create a reproducible test case, using `1.0.0` of the Room artifacts, I'd file an issue.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your help. It was really stupid mistake from my side, I used another int attribute as input param for uid so problem solved. Problem was between the computer and the chair :)

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working!

Answer (score 3):

Use delete query like this:

```
@Query("Delete FROM Orders where quote_no LIKE :quote_no")
void deleteOrderById(String quote_no);
```

where `quote_no` is the unique value in the data base with which you want to delete the row and `Orders` is the table name.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `@Query` this way.

```
 @Query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE uid = :arg0")
 int delete(final int noteId);
```

In the above code of lines, arg0 is the first argument passed to the function delete().

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22112535)

Comment: This solved to me. Just an observation, the diference for my code was that I didn't put the return (int). I'm using Kotlin with suspend functions.

Comment: @LeonardoCosta happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @Delete annotation and all of the parameters of the Delete method must either be classes annotated with Entity or collections/array of it.

In your case, I believe, that you should use 
@Delete
int delete(Note note) or

@Delete
int delete(Note... note)

Comment: According comments it was different issue and OP solved it, but this answer is pretty OK IMHO. Could you please add some references to documentation for future readers?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've added the wrong delete annotation @DELETE which was imported from retrofit instead of @Delete which is imported from room libraries.